# Check Permission:media_record while stating call recording

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

Below is logcat while starting call recording.

```
 08:43:07.656 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 23
06-14 08:43:07.657 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 2
06-14 08:43:07.658 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 22
06-14 08:43:07.658 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 11
06-14 08:43:07.670 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 12
06-14 08:43:07.673 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 14
06-14 08:43:07.684 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 16
06-14 08:43:07.685 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 8
06-14 08:43:09.692 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: media_record-code= 7
06-14 08:43:09.811 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android W/ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO from uid=10165 pid=4982
06-14 08:43:09.811 4982-4982/com.callrecorder.android E/CheckPermission: Permission Denial: can't record pid=4982, uid=10165
06-14 08:43:09.811 4982-498
```

Though all permission are in manifest as below:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

I m testing on oppo f1s with lollipop installed.

can someone suggest why still getting permission error and how to fix it. What permission still not captured?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution , it was permission issue in mobile , oppo has given additional security for app which was not enabled.

Goto Security>App permissions and choose app and give permission manually even in lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Permanent and better solution:

From Marshmallow you have to check runtime permission.
Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

See detail at:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

You can follow this link for detail solution: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow

If you want to work smartly, I recommend using github android library:
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: Thanks for input, you comment and information is valid and I m using same way. The issue was with Lollipop and oppo f1s only, this code is  running fine on other devices otherwise.